# Apache 2.4.18, 403: Forbidden

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I'm using Apache 2.4.18 on Ubuntu 16.04. I have 2 disks on my Ubuntu server, HDD and SSD. On HDD there is installed Apache, and on SSD is installed directory which I want to access from browser.

The server just returns 403: Forbidden.

Here is what I tried. Created in `apache2.conf`:

```
# DocumentRoot or ServerRoot is commented

Alias /weblink /directory/on/ssd
...

<Directory /weblink>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Changed the CHMOD to 777.
Changed the CHOWN to root user.

Apache is giving me this error:

```
[Mon Jul 03 00:10:32.362552 2017] [authz_core:error] [pid 1332] [client 31.xxx.xxx.xxx:59063] AH01630: client denied by server configuration:
```

I really do not know what to do at this point, and it drives me crazy. I've been searching for solution for a couple of hours, but still didn't find the solution.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<Directory /weblink>
```

it should be:

```
<Directory /directory/on/ssd>
```

The `/weblink` is a URL `Location`, not a `Directory`.

Comment: Thanks. This just shows my stupidity and fact that I am new to Linux.

Comment: Not a Linux issue, more to do with Apache configuration. Many would argue that configuring Apache is a black art, so don't feel concerned that you mixed it up.